Get all attachments for issue on Jenkins pipeline with JIRA Pipeline Steps plugin
I am struggling with the "JIRA Pipeline Steps" plugin: Given I have an Jira Issue number and I would like to download the attachments to the Jenkins working directory.
The method jiraDownloadAttachment expects the attachment id. But there is no other method including jiraGetIssue where I can find the attachment id by Jira issue id.
Do I need to specify some more query parameters on jiraGetIssue, so all linked attachments are getting listed?
